# How can I do bit operate with BLOB?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to generate parity value with string variables.

For example, with 'a' and 'b', I want to get value ''.

You may know what I mean :

```
var a = 'a';    // 01100001
var b = 'b';    // 01100010
var temp = a^b; // My expectation : 00000011
alert(temp);    // My expectation :
```

I have searched some related things, such as converting a character to binary, etc.

but I couldn't get what I want.

Is it impossible to operate with string variable which is not 'number' directly in JavaScript?

Any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the function that you have used ? String.charCodeAt('a') ??

Comment: Not sure that there is another way to do that https://jsfiddle.net/0c6qb4yg/

Comment: @e.m.b I tried, but the return value of string.charCodeAt() method is number. So, if the binary is '00000001', what I get is just '1'. If I add the leadingzeros, I can convert the '1' to '00000001' but, it will be string. Then, how could I do bit operate, again? I believe I misunderstand something, please help.

Comment: there's the >>> operator for adding leading zeros, check the mozilla doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: @Kirill Thank you. You gave me what I want. I could solve this problem with your snippet. Thanks, again

Comment: @e.m.b Thank you for let me know about it. It helped me a lot to solve the problem.